# Change WPF window Size programmatically in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

How do you change the size of your Window in WPF programmatically using an MVVM approach?

I am setting the window height to 400 from XAML and on click of a button on the form trying to increase the height to 500.

In my button's ICommand I am using:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.Height = 500;
```

But it's not doing anything.

Answer (score 8):

Try setting the 'Application.Current.MainWindow' property in the `Loaded` event in the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file:

```
private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.MainWindow = this;
}
```

UPDATE >>>

My friend, please remember, *you* said you wanted to use `Application.Current.MainWindow`... this is how you could use it. However, if you want to do this the MVVM way, then why don't you just bind the value to the `Window.Width` properties?

```
<Window Width="{Binding Width}" MinWidth="{Binding Width}" MaxWidth="{Binding Width}">
    ...
</Window>
```

Please note that binding to `Window.Width` is *not* enough for this to work.

Comment: There is nothing in MVVM that says that you *can't* use the code behind.

Comment: @user2519971 Actually, using code-behind is right in this case. In the context of MVVM, ViewModel should not know about View. So manipulating View in VM is a bad practice defeating purpose of MVVM.

Comment: @Sheridan. you are right. I tried setting Window Width="{Binding Width}" but its not working. what is the catch in this ?

Comment: Why is `Window.Width` not enough?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write the Framework, so I really can't guess why they made it like that... it could be a bug, an oversight, or perhaps they made it like that for some unknown reason.

Comment: The correct way is to add Mode=TwoWay to the binding then Window.Widht is enough.

Comment: Hi @NeilB, please add an answer to share your knowledge with the SO community.

Comment: OK, see my answer at the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar requirement to this, with the addition that I wanted to track some other window settings. So, I have this class:

```
public class WindowSettings
{
    public int Width { get; set; }

    public int Height { get; set; }

    public int Left { get; set; }

    public int Top { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my view model, I have:

```
public WindowSettings WindowSettings
{
    get
    {
        return _windowSettings;
    }
}
```

and in the xaml, this:

```
<Window ...
    Height="{Binding WindowSettings.Height,Mode=TwoWay}"
    Width="{Binding WindowSettings.Width, Mode=TwoWay}"
Left="{Binding WindowSettings.Left,Mode=TwoWay}"
    Top="{Binding WindowSettings.Top,Mode=TwoWay}">
```

If I wanted to programmatically update the width, for example, I do this:

```
WindowSettings.Width = 456;
RaisePropertyChangedEvent("WindowSettings.Width");
```

(Naturally, my view model inherits from a base class which implements INotifyPropertyChanged.)

I did toy with the idea of providing an event on the WindowSettings class so that an update to a property could automatically cause the property change notification, but my requirement is to track the window size and set it on startup, so I didn't bother. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Using VS 2017 and Caliburn Micro I have no issue with just setting the width. The way you are doing it isn't MVVM your VM doesn't need to know about the V or what's happening when the int Width changes.

```
public class ShellViewModel : Caliburn.Micro.PropertyChangedBase, IShell
{
    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        Width = 500;
    }
    private int _width;
    public int Width
    {
        get => _width;
        set
        {
            _width = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Width);
        }
    }
    public void MyButton()
    {
        Width = 800;
    }

}
```

In the Window XAML

```
Width="{Binding Width, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

In the Grid

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Content="Make 800 wide" />
```

it opens at 500 and when I click the button it stretches to 800.

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this answer because the most voted answer actually isn't correct. Binding to the MinHeight & MaxHeight, will result in a window that can't be resized using the grips.

```
<Window Width="{Binding Width}" MinWidth="{Binding Width}" MaxWidth="{Binding Width}">
    ...
</Window>
```

Instead add `Mode=TwoWay` to your binding.

```
<Window Width="{Binging Width, Mode=TwoWay}">
    ...
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the window you want to resize is MainWindow? Or are you sure your command is successfully binding on your button? You can try the below code:

View:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.ViewModel"
        Title="Wpf Application" Height="300" Width="400"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModel:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Resize" Command="{Binding ResizeCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding ResizeCommand.CanExecute}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    private RelayCommand _resizeCommand;

    public RelayCommand ResizeCommand { get { return _resizeCommand; } }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        this._resizeCommand = new RelayCommand(this.Resize);
    }

    private void Resize()
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Height = 500;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Works

```
Application.Current.MainWindow = this;
Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
Application.Current.MainWindow.Width = 800;
Application.Current.MainWindow.Height = 450;
```

Comment: Hi CodeGen, thanks for your answer. This code block may address the question, but it isn't very helpful to others. Consider explaining why this solves the asker's question, and why what they tried didn't work; otherwise, they might make the same mistake again.

Comment: this answer might be correct, but please explain how it is working. That way it helps others who is following the qtn